# Is it possible to have database-wide table aliases?

Tags: postgresql

I am about to model a PostgreSQL database, based on an Oracle database. The latter is old and its tables have been named after a 3-letter-scheme.

E.g. a table that holds parameters for tasks would be named `TSK_PAR`.

As I model the new database, I'd like to rename those tables to a more descriptive name using actual words. My problem is, that some parts of the software might rely on these old names until they're rewritten and adapted to the new scheme.

Is it possible to create something like an alias that's being used for the whole database?

E.g. I create a new `task_parameters` database, but add a `TSK_PAR` alias to it, so if a `SELECT * FROM TSK_PAR` is being used, it automatically refers to the new name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has no synonyms like Oracle.

But for your intended use case, views should do just fine. A view that simply does `select * from taks_parameters` is automatically updateable (see [here](https://rextester.com/SOOJ52924) for an online example).

If you don't want to clutter your default schema (usually `public`) with all those views, you can create them in a different schema, and then adjust the user's [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) to include that "synonym schema".

For example:

```
create schema synonyms;

create table public.task_parameters (
  id integer primary key, 
  ....
);

create view synonyms.task_par
as
select *
from public.task_parameters;
```

---

However, that approach has one annoying drawback: if a table is used by a view, the allowed DDL statements on it are limited, e.g. you can't drop a column or rename it.

As we manage our schema migrations using Liquibase, we always drop all views before applying "normal" migrations, then once everything is done, we simply re-create all views (by running the SQL scripts stored in Git). With that approach, ALTER TABLE statements never fail because there are not views using the tables. As creating a view is really quick, it doesn't add overhead when deploying a migration.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning! This would be the go-to for a read-only table, yes. In my scenario I also have to UPDATE and DELETE there, so a view is not acceptable :/ At least how I understand them

Comment: @Trollwut: as I wrote:  a view defined like that is automatically updateable in Postgres: https://rextester.com/SOOJ52924

Comment: thanks mate, this looks very promosing! I'm going to test stuff with this approach :)

Comment: Seems like this is pretty well what I'm looking for, I can work with that. Merce dir!